# set tikz options through pgfkeys

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, tcolorbox

I'm using `tcolorbox` and using `pgfkeys` to set some of the tikz options. But they do not seem to be working. Consider the MWE given below. If I set draw color using `\pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, fill=red, draw=green, color=blue}` the color is not set and the overlay has black color, as if no color is set. Neither the `\tikzset` nor the `\pgfkeys` seems to be working. If I set color in `\draw` command, it is working. What's missing ?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{fill=red, draw=brown}
\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
  overlay={%
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}%
      \pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, fill=red, draw=green, color=blue}
      \draw[line width=0.5cm] (interior.north west) -- (interior.south east);%
      \draw[line width=0.5cm] (interior.south west) -- (interior.north east);%
    \end{tcbclipinterior}%
}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you want to do `\tikzset{every path/.append style={fill=red, draw=green, color=blue}}`? Are you aware that the `color` option overwrites any previous set `fill` and `draw` color and that a straight line will not have any area to fill?

Comment: I'm aware `color` option overwrites previous set `fill` and `draw` color. What I was expecting is some color to show up instead of black. If I remove `color=blue`, `draw` color is still defined and I want to see the green color lines in the interior.

Comment: Well, the options only apply to the current path and not to following paths (hence the `every path` style). Could you elaborate what you want to achieve? I don’t know the `tcolorbox` package but I assume that they are styles, settings or macros to change the visual outcome of the box.

Comment: I'm trying to give user an option to set color and hence trying to set the color through `pgfkeys`. `every path` answered my question. Thx

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the exact question, but I don't see any problem defining a `style` which can be later used inside `overlay`.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{mystyle/.style={fill=red, draw=brown}}

\begin{tcolorbox}[enhanced,
  overlay={%
    \begin{tcbclipinterior}%
%      \pgfkeys{/tikz/.cd, fill=red, draw=green, color=blue}
      \draw[mystyle,line width=0.5cm] (interior.north west) -- (interior.south east);%
      \draw[mystyle,line width=0.5cm] (interior.south west) -- (interior.north east);%
    \end{tcbclipinterior}%
}]
\lipsum[1]
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]